# What are the must have reports to monitor production?

Tags: .net, iis, report

We are rolling out our product to production and I am really interested in knowing what kind of reports are worth having to understand production behavior? I know I can look at perfmon/appmon on application's use of servers. Is there any MUST have reports that are to measure the product behaviour in production apart from the pref and app mon? If there are reports worth building into the application to monitor? Our application is .Net runs on IIS.

** It is a web solution build using client side with AngularJS and server side is with WebAPI. ** I want to see if the WebAPI part works properly.

Comment: At least tell us... is it a web app? a phone app? an embedded app?

Answer (score 0):

try Newrelic, there's a free subscription. You will never use something else.

(I don't work for them)